# helm-do-grep-ag vs helm-do-ag, differences?

Tags: helm-ag

I don't know exactly the differences between helm-do-grep-ag and helm-do-ag, couldn't find any description. Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Where is helm-do-ag defined? I have helm-do-grep-ag only.

Comment: I guess it's part of the helm-ag package?